# Why 95% confidence interval is different for some studies in meta-analysis in “meta” package in r?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, meta-analysis

I am trying to do a meta-analysis using hazard ratio, lower and upper 95% confidence interval in meta package in R but for example Blazek study, obtained upper and lower 95%CI ([0.6023; 1.5944]) were different than the original values (0.51-1.35) and I do not know how to get the exact numbers.

NB: I asked a similar question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63106936/why-i-am-getting-different-95-confidence-interval-for-some-studies-in-meta-anal/63110191#63110191) and they advised me to ask it here but this has different examples that I am struggling to solve.

**Any advice will be greatly appreciated.**

**Used code:**

```
data<-read.table(text="studlab  HR      LCI     UCI 
                          Blazek    0.98    0.51    1.35 
                          ARTS      1.05    0.71    1.55
                          EXCEL     1.38    1.03    1.85
                          BEST      1.34    0.77    2.34
", header=T, sep="\t") 

metagen(log(HR), lower = log(LCI), upper = log(UCI),
        studlab = studlab,data=data, sm = "HR")
```

**Results**

```
                                     HR           95%-CI %W(fixed) %W(random)
                          Blazek 0.9800 [0.6023; 1.5944]      16.4       16.4
                          ARTS   1.0500 [0.7106; 1.5514]      25.5       25.5
                          EXCEL  1.3800 [1.0297; 1.8495]      45.4       45.4
                          BEST   1.3400 [0.7687; 2.3360]      12.6       12.6

Number of studies combined: k = 4

                         HR           95%-CI    z p-value
Fixed effect model   1.2120 [0.9950; 1.4764] 1.91  0.0561
Random effects model 1.2120 [0.9950; 1.4764] 1.91  0.0561

Quantifying heterogeneity:
 tau^2 = 0 [0.0000; 0.3768]; tau = 0 [0.0000; 0.6138];
 I^2 = 0.0% [0.0%; 78.4%]; H = 1.00 [1.00; 2.15]

Test of heterogeneity:
    Q d.f. p-value
 2.13    3  0.5456

Details on meta-analytical method:
- Inverse variance method
- DerSimonian-Laird estimator for tau^2
- Jackson method for confidence interval of tau^2 and tau
```

Answer (score 3):

If you take the Blazek study and examine the confidence interval you will see the problem straight away.

0.98 / 0.51  =  1.92

but

1.35  / 0.98  =  1.38

They should be equal since hazard ratio is on a multiplicative scale but they clearly are not. Assuming you checked when you transcribed them then I think there must be an error in the original source.

Comment: Thx a lot for your feedback. I see your point. Upvoted!